# MongoDB one compound index vs multiple single field indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection of photos. They can be referenced (one-to-many) from some other collections (events, news, posts, etc)

I can create reference like this:

```
db.photos.insert({ parent:{ collection: 'events', id: 12345 }})
db.photos.insert({ parent:{ collection: 'events', id: 54321 }})
//or just DBRef
db.photos.ensureIndex({parent:1})
```

OR

```
db.photos.insert({ post_id: 12345 })
db.photos.insert({ event_id: 54321 })

db.photos.ensureIndex({post_id:1}, {sparse: true})
db.photos.ensureIndex({event_id:1}, {sparse: true})
```

In the first case we have one big compound index
In the second — some number of smaller indexes

What's pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: The first case is a sub-document index, not a compound index.  See the docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/) to get a basic understanding of the differences.  Asking for the pros and cons of each approach is too broad a question.

Comment: since each photo could be referenced from many places, have you considered storing the photo ID in appropriate event collection rather than event in the photo collection?   To know which is "better" and the trade-offs, you would need to consider how you will be querying for this information (since schema and indexes should be optimized based on the queries you will be using, not data itself in isolation).

Comment: Basically the answer is: it depends on your queries.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, thanks, of course, I know the difference. just mixed it up, because I was also thinking about two separete fields variant //parent_collection and parent_id

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, Yes, I considered this variant and moreover this is how it is realized now. But I also need to show separate list of photos. And I'a sure that while showing events one additional query to photos collection is better then many queries to events while showing photos.

Comment: @Sammaye, Now I need queries like this
db.photos.find().sort({created:-1}) and
db.events.findOne({_id:12345}) + db.photos.find({event_id: 12345})

But it whould be great, if someone can explain more general difference in performance of retrieving/inserting, memory consumption etc if using multiple sparse indexes vs one big sub-document/compound index
thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, check the number of hits on which field.
Second, create one compound index with max hit fields.
Third, create one compound index with min hit fields.

Note: 
If a large number of fields hit at a time than used compound indexing.
Other cases create single indexing.